# Tumblr Shape HTML

Tags: html, tumblr, shapes

Okay so i just started a Tumblr blog the other day, and when i was editing the profile page i had happily found a edit with HTML button, and i thought wow now i can finally loose this (image below) that's intruding on my theme.

[image: ugly shape border]

So, I hit <kbd>CTRL + F</kbd> to find code relating to the shape, and found that the shape was actually a fill rather than a preset image, so i entered the hex code for a transparent black `#00000000)`, but to no avail, it didn't work, and after about an hour or so of scouring the web, I decided to reach out, and was possibly hoping that someone with HTML experience could help, anyways here's the [code](http://pastebin.com/BE6DifE0)

Comment: Can you actually link to your tumblr? Then it can be inspected in the browser quickly and it's easier to pinpoint the code associated with it (rather than the whole theme being pasted in pastebin).

Comment: Please provide a link to your Tumblr, otherwise its not possible to help you out.

Comment: @iharby http://ruricolus.tumblr.com/

Comment: @damek132 http://ruricolus.tumblr.com/

Answer (score 0):

Right the background you should be able to change within your template settings as this is just a background you need to change. This is not something within the HTML template - I am not sure how to change background in Tumblr but look within profile or theme settings, widgets or block.

Answer (score 0):

Use inspect element and you will see this:

```
.header-image.cover {
    background-image: url(http://static.tumblr.com/d3c51755c609fd193d623381320efcb6/kcvyami/oSJnx6juu/tumblr_static_tumblr_static_jqy1bj0w774s0o04wc4wsskc_focused_v3.gif);
}
```

The image that you are looking for is found here:
http://static.tumblr.com/d3c51755c609fd193d623381320efcb6/kcvyami/oSJnx6juu/tumblr_static_tumblr_static_jqy1bj0w774s0o04wc4wsskc_focused_v3.gif

If you're looking to delete the doge image, then delete this from the HTML:

```
<figure class="avatar-wrapper animate">
    <a href="/" style="background-image: url(http://33.media.tumblr.com/avatar_e1fbc1eda419_128.png)" class="user-avatar">
        <img src="http://33.media.tumblr.com/avatar_e1fbc1eda419_128.png" alt="" class="print-only invisible">
    </a>
</figure>
```